# gem included in gemfile still requires "include" in class file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've included the gem for aasm (https://github.com/aasm/aasm) in my Gemfile and run bundle install a bunch of times. However, the commands from the plugin won't work until I add "include AASM" to my file (user.rb in particular). Why is this? I can't think of any reason why I should still need to do this--isn't this the whole point of bundler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple concepts that you'll want to understand about what is going on here:

In Rails, the Gemfile contains the libraries (gems) that you want bundler to download and make available to your app. These are automatically made available in Rails, where as in a standalone Ruby program, you would need the 'require' command for each library that you want to use. 'require' literally runs the file that is required (akin but not exactly the same as the '#include' directive in C++ and the 'import' in Java). The required file may add some kind of global functionality, or it may not. With the AASMgem, the functionality isn't desirable in all classes, so you decide which classes will use it with...

The Ruby command 'include' allows you to 'mix in' functionality from a module (module AASM in the following example, see: https://github.com/aasm/aasm/blob/master/lib/aasm/aasm.rb). Look at the following example from the AASM doc:

```
require 'aasm'

class Job
  include AASM

  aasm do
    state :stage1, :initial => true
    state :stage2
    ...
  end
end
```

So, the 'require' statement is unnecessary in Rails, since Rails will have already requires the library for you. The 'include' statement mixes the state machine methods into the Job class. Specifically in this example, it gives you the 'aasm' method (that's a method, to which you're passing a block with the 'do'). The 'aasm' method does some stuff, and executes the block (which also uses the AASM-specific 'state' method in this example).

The main point here in relation to your original question is that the 'aasm' method does not exist in the Job class until you 'include AASM'. This also means, that other classes do not automatically have the AASM methods (which keeps the Object namespace clean).

The only way that you will get functionality in all classes by using the 'require' command is if the required file monkey patches Object (this is rarely done since it can be dangerous), otherwise, you'll generally be given a new kind of class to use or a collection of methods contained in a module that you can mix in to your own classes.

Answer (score 1):

Bundler and the Gemfile take care of downloading the code, and making it available to your app. This is typically done by using `require`.

Writing `include AASM` adds the state machine functionality to your `User` class.

Many Ruby gems work this way: bundler requires the gem, which loads the code into the app, and then separately you use `include` to add the functionality to a specific model, controller, etc.